# "one or more" with LL parser

Tags: algorithm, parsing, grammar, ll-grammar

Let's say my grammar is:

```
file = line, {line}
line = ..., "\n"
```

If I want to build a LL parser for that grammar, how should I implement the "one or more line"?

I was thinking about changing the grammar to this:

```
file = line
line = ..., "\n", nl
nl = line
   | <end of file>
```

My lines would be nested. Is this the most elegant/efficient way to solve the problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close. Typically just like this:

```
file = line, morelines
morelines = e | line, morelines
line = ..., "\n"
```

Where e is the epsilon or empty symbol

Comment: Great, thank you. I didn't know about the empty symbol. This makes more sense as the method can be reused for most grammars